# Laravel Passport login user by custom method, without password

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-passport

Hello I am using Passport as auth provider.

Now I need to login an user programmatically, skipping the password requirement, creating the authtoken and all.

This is what I am trying:

User model

```
//Return user instance by username
public function LoadByEmail($email) 
{
    return $this->where('email', $email)->first();
}
```

AuthController->login

```
    $email = 'existing@email.com';
    $exists = User::EmailExists($email); //user already exists

    if($exists) {
        $user = new User;
        $currentUser = $user->LoadByEmail($email);

        $currentUser = auth()->login($currentUser);
    }
```

CurrentUser is null.
How do I login an eisting user by its email?

Comment: I have never heard of the method `LoadByEmail`. Does it exist. If it doesn't can you try using `$currentUser= User::whereEmail($email)->first()`; Then, try doing: `Auth::login($user)`

Comment: It's a custem method I created, I think your method t load user would be equivalent and I will try it.

Shoult I use Auth:: ? Isn't Passport using its own auth method?

Comment: Ideally Auth::login would work on your session or on the default `web` driver mentioned in  `auth.php`.

Comment: does your first `$currentUser`  return the user object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this :

```
$email = 'existing@email.com';
$user = User::where('email',$email)->first() ;
if($user) {
        
  Auth::loginUsingId($user->id, true);

}
```

the namespace of `Auth` is `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;`

Comment: Yes, this is the right way! Don't know why auth()->login() does not work